# How do carrier RNAs increase yield in sequencing experiments?

Tags: dna-sequencing, rna-sequencing

I would like to know how carrier RNAs increase yield in RNA/DNA sequencing experiments. Is their main function in the precipitation steps of each protocol (i.e. small quantities are difficult to precipitate and the carrier RNAs add material), or do they have a role at other stages in the process as well?

Comment: What kind of sequencing methods and which step in the method are you talking about? In many cases, carrier is added to visualize precipitates and/or get efficient precipitation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding phenol-chloroform extracted tRNA then that is a carrier for the precipitation steps. Some people use linear acrylamide for the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but this does not answer my question. Are carrier RNAs used at other steps in preparation for sequencing?

Comment: I've used glycogen for this too.